# Why table view cell 's textFiled never change?

Tags: swift, macos

[image: my xib storyboard as follow ：]
[image]

[image: the result is this]

==================================================================

```
class ViewController: NSViewController,NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet weak var sidebarView: NSTableView!

func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {

    return 9
}


func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {

    let tableCellView = tableView.make(withIdentifier: tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView

    let str:String = (tableColumn?.identifier)!
    if str == "SIDEBAR_ITEM" {
        tableCellView!.textField?.stringValue = "test"
        print(tableCellView!.textField?.stringValue)
    }
    return tableCellView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, rowViewForRow row: Int) -> NSTableRowView? {
    //print("rowViewForRow")
    return NSTableRowView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))

}}
```

==================================================================

what's wrong about this? Is that any error config ? it's alway show "Table View Cell"

Comment: When you run your code, what is the actual value of `str` inside your `objectValueFor` method?

Comment: Do you know that the protocol `NSTableViewDelegate` declares a method `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)` and when you should implement it? (One more, you should better show your code as text, not by image.)

Comment: the value of str is the same as the compare value "SIDEBAR_ITEM", I also implement the tableView(_:viewFor:row:) methoe as your say ,but it never change the title

Comment: The implementation of `objectValueFor` is wrong. Usually you have to return `dataSourceArray[row]`

Answer (score 0):

finally , I find the problem!
I missing implement the method "tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?"

Answer (score 0):

tableView(_:viewFor:row:) is a delegate method not a data source method. Unless you specify the tableView as conforming to the NSTableViewDelegate protocol the method will not be called. This was confusing me as I thought it was a source method.